# How to create object inside object in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object inside an object in JavaScript like this:

```
    {
      "test": {
        {},
        {}
      }
    }
```

In more detail, I want to create a new object if "test" doesn't exist in the object, and create a new object in the same location as the old one if "test" exists.

Please help if this is possible.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to get at with the `{}, {}` though. That doesn't look valid/meaningful. I'll ignore it for now and use your words instead.

Comment: _“a new object if `test` doesn't exist in the object”_ — so you want to incorporate conditionals in your object literal? Please review the documentation for [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [edit] your question and clarify what you need. `{{}, {}}` isn’t a valid expression.

Answer (score 2):

You mean, like:

```
theObject["test"] = {};
```

this?

It's just an assignment, mate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a key in every object you create in JavaScript.

E.g.:

```
var obj = {
  objInside: {}
}
```

you can read more about [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: I’ve replaced the old link for three reasons: W3Schools isn’t that reputable of a resource (MDN is one of the most reputable resources), [there’s no such thing as a “JSON Object”](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (W3Schools got that one wrong…), and the question is completely unrelated to JSON.

Comment: great thanks a lot..